# RSQLServer: Cannot begin a nested transaction after dbRollback

Tags: sql-server, r, r-dbi

**Background**

In my database I have some uniqueness constraints. If the data breaks one of this conditions, I get an error message like `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint`.

I use `tryCatch` in my code, to capture this error and return a meaningful message to the user. So far so good.

However, if I try to run any new transaction on the server after having captured this error, I get another error message saying that I `Cannot begin a nested transaction.`

**My findings**

I traced the error down, and I figured that when `dbRollback` is called (either explicitly, or within `withTransaction`) one cannot submit any new `dbBegin` anymore (either explicitly or implicitly via `dbWriteTable` and friends).

What I need to get unstuck, is to run a `dbCommit`, to be allowed to run another `dbBegin`.

Looking at the code of `dbCommit` and `dbRollback` I see that in the former case 
`setAutoCommit` is set to true, which signals `dbBegin` that we are not nesting transactions. This is not the case for `dbRollback`:

```
getMethod("dbCommit", "SQLServerConnection")
# Method Definition:
# 
# function (conn, ...) 
# {
#     rJava::.jcall(conn@jc, "V", "commit")
#     rJava::.jcall(conn@jc, "V", "setAutoCommit", TRUE)
#     TRUE
# }
# <environment: namespace:RSQLServer>    

getMethod("dbRollback", "SQLServerConnection")
# Method Definition:
# 
# function (conn, ...) 
# {
#     rJava::.jcall(conn@jc, "V", "rollback")
#     TRUE
# }
# <environment: namespace:RSQLServer>
```

**Question**

So my question is: is this the supposed behavior? That is, am I suppose to run a manual `dbCommit` after an operation was rolled back, or is this a bug?

**Code**

```
 library(DBI)
 library(RSQLServer)
 db <- dbConnect(...)
 dbBegin(db)
 dbCommit(db)

 dbBegin(db) # works
 dbRollback(db)

 dbBegin(db) # does not work

 dbCommit(db) # my workaround
 dbBegin(db) # works again
```

Comment: This looks like a problem in RSQLServer to me. Maybe file an issue in its GitHub repo?

Comment: Will do. Thanks!